How do you approach problems like these where we have to find the arrangement of resistors?

Is there any specific methodology to approach them or is it just intuition? Because I am finding them really hard.

There are some basic things that can be gleamed. The only way to get a 0.5ohm resistance is using two 1ohms in parallel. The only way to get 3 ohms is three 1ohm resistors in series. That eats up 5. So those then have to be your building blocks. Connections don't have to be at the ends and can be in the middle.

the .5 is associated with A, so that is where you connect it

Basically it's just a logic puzzle. But it's possible to be systematic about it. In this case, since B-C is 3 ohms, and there have to be some resistors left over, there should be 3 resistors in series between B and C. Since both of the values involving A end in ".5", there are probably two resistors in parallel attached to A, making a half-ohm. That adds up to exactly five resistors, and from there it's not hard to see that

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
is a solution.

A policy of this site is not to give away the answers to school work.

@AnalogKid the purpose of exercises is to learn. It's not a test. The professor would walk through a few examples from the problem book in the same way, to motivate the solution of the rest of them.

"the purpose of exercises is to learn. "  Yes, but, everything after that is stuff you do not actually know to be true.  For all we know, this could be a take-home final exam.  There are many, many threads on this and other sites where the first comment is the question "Is this schoolwork?"

But what do they learn if another does the thinking for them.

@StainlessSteelRat they learn how to do it, by seeing it done and following the explanation. Not everyone invents everything from first principles every time.

You learn nothing if you are given the answer.  They will fail when tested because they did not have an opportunity to apply first principles.  Hopefully, the answers will be given on the test.

@hobbs  If you look at your rep you will notice a sudden inexplicable spike. It appears that someone has gone through your many good high rep answers and upvoted a number that well deserve the upvote. It looks like this approximately balances out the blip from the downvotes on this answer. || While I appreciate the spirit in which you answered this (really), it is usually wise to lead the student toward the answer and not provide the full solution for them.

In this case they were asking for method, not a given problem's solution, and that is what you gave them. BUT some may not see it that way and it can pay to err on the side of the group mind's perception. [[Determining what the group mind's perception is is the trick :-) ]]
